# Первая буква в описании всплывающих подсказок

Tags: поддержка, локализация, термины

Каком образом следует писать первую букву в всплывающих подсказках?

На данный момент, найти логику, в текущем переводе на Transifex, невозможно - все переводы хаотичны: часть начинаются со строчной (маленькой), часть с заглавной (большой).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Публиковать везде и всюду все подсказки с заглавной буквы. (*Комментарий к ответу*: Если это полноценное предложение (есть подлежащее и сказуемое), то начинать с заглавной буквы и заканчивать точкой — всегда. Если это надпись, то есть варианты. Без примеров не очень ясно, про какие подсказки речь.)

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Вариант 1. Можно просто следовать английскому:

  - там прописная - в русском переводе тоже прописная
  - там строчная - в русском переводе тоже строчная
- Вариант 2. В качестве альтернативного варианта, публиковать подсказки с заглавной буквы, если они составляют законченное предложение, в противном случае — со строчной.