# Краткое описание метки и точка в конце предложения

Tags: обсуждение, стиль

Предыстория. Я увидел, что в кратком описании метки [language-lawyer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) отсутствует завершающая точка и выглядит это так:

> [image: всплывающий блок]

Или вот так, [в описании метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info):

> [image: описание метки]

Т.к. [привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) для единоличного редактирования описания меток у меня пока нет, моя [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/138144) была поставлена в очередь на проверку, и в последствии была отклонена.

По результатам этого действия произошёл [диалог в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35020627#35020627) с одним из отклонивших правку участником и в последствии им был задан [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/429747/183872) в сообществе *Русский язык*. Полноценного ответа вопрос не получил, более того, его [предложено было закрыть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429747/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8#comment433606_429747) с формулировкой:

> Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что относится к вёрстке электронных текстов.

Было предложено [руководствоваться эстетическими соображениями](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429747/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8#comment433613_429747).

Несмотря на всевозможные неоднозначности с точки зрения того как это должно выглядеть по правилам русского языка, сейчас я хочу узнать мнение сообщества на этот счёт.

**Хотим ли мы видеть точку в конце предложения, выступающего в качестве краткого описания метки?**

Замечу, что большинство существующих меток с описанием содержит точку в конце предложения. Исключения на текущий момент [были обнаружены](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35021602#35021602) для меток [php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [.htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess), [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).

### Обновление

Нашел вот такой [ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/476/176217):

> Публиковать **везде и всюду все подсказки** с заглавной буквы. (Комментарий к ответу: Если это полноценное предложение (есть подлежащее и сказуемое), **то начинать с заглавной буквы и заканчивать точкой — всегда**. Если это надпись, то есть варианты. Без примеров не очень ясно, про какие подсказки речь.)

Думаю, теперь всё должно быть ясно,

Comment: Кхе, кто-то ещё и вопрос минусует :) Подсказка, голосовать надо за ответы.

Comment: Значит этот кто-то вообще не хочет такого обсуждения (наверное догадывается, какой из вариантов победит в условиях демократии)

Comment: оформление подсказок относится к типографике языка. в [вопросе на rus.so](http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/429747/176866) я привёл ссылку на соответствующий справочник, где говорится о ненужности точки в конце **текста подписи к иллюстрации**, что весьма по смыслу схоже (с моей точки зрения) с текстом всплывающей подсказки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в 85 году никто из авторов упомянутого справочника еще не догадывался о том, что такое *всплывающая подсказка*.

Comment: @alexolut не голосовал, но процитирую хинт стрелки вниз: "данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться, он непонятен или не несет пользы". Вполне вероятно, что для кого-то вопрос "не несет пользы".

Comment: @Kromster и какой момент из цитаты Вам кажется более подходящим? Хинт, если хотите, можем подправить :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Точка нужна.

Answer (score 3):

вопрос о точке в конце текста всплывающей подсказки относится лишь к эстетике (дизайну, типографике) оформления.

точка может ставиться, а может не ставиться — по эстетическим соображениям редактирующего.

Comment: Тоже плюсую, наравне с "Точка нужна".

Comment: Я считаю, что здесь в первую очередь должно быть единообразие. Метки - это как "общие" сообщения, должны быть в едином стиле. К тому же, проще добавить 4 точки в 4 метках, чем убрать 100 точек в 100 метках. Но с точкой всё равно выглядит симпатичнее и не создается ощущения незаконченности предложения (основной смысл точки).

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Вы предлагаете этим ответом оставить всё как есть в кратком описании меток? И решение о точке должно приниматься редактором описания самостоятельно?

Comment: @alexolut, да, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тогда я против, так как считаю, что должно быть единообразно для всех меток.

Answer (score 1):

Точка нужна, только если в описании более одного предложения
(идею высказал в чате @Nofate)

Answer (score 0):

Точка не нужна

Comment: Я не ставлю точку во всплывающих подсказках, даже если подсказка оформлена оконченным предложением, потому что люблю лаконичные короткие тексты. Описание меток лично я читаю во всплывающих подсказках, а не на странице метки.

Comment: @Mae т.е. на странице метки точка нужна, а во всплывающей подсказке нет? Но к сожалению, это один и тот же текст.

Comment: К сожалению, да, но на странице с описанием без точки и с точкой смотрится одинаково хорошо. На мой вкус лучше без точки, но я не настаиваю, что это единственно верный вариант.